# C# - Calling a Delegate with 'params string[]' from a Dynamic Method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ilgenerator

Is it possible to call a `delegate` that takes as a parameter `params string[]` from a dynamic method?

**Example:**

```
delegate string Del(params string[] arg);
...
Del f = args => "Called successfully.";
...
var mb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                    "MyMethod",
                    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
                    typeof(string),
                    new Type[] {typeof(string), typeof(string)});
...
var generator = mb.GetILGenerator();
...
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
...
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, f.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"));
```

Because whenever I run the code above, it gives me this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What version of the framework is this? (nvm, I see dotnet core)

Comment: @clarkitect dotnet core 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the array of strings. The "params" keyword is just for syntactic sugar in c#/vb but is ignored in IL.

Comment: Didn't know that 'params' is a syntactic sugar. Thx